# What does "out back" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "out back" mean in this sentence? Does it mean the back of house?

> Kelly: Dad! Dad! Where is father? Wasn't he out back?
>   
> Clay: I don't know.

Or it is somewhere out of town?

Comment: "out back" is "outside, in back of the house", also commonly referred to as "the back yard".

Comment: Unless you're in Australia.

Comment: @HotLicks which is practically the same thing as back yard if you're a sheep farmer...

Answer (score 2):

In this context "out back" means outside the house, in the back (yard).  The person would still be on the property, so not too far away.

Comment: Note that in a business it might mean "in the back room" or some such.  Eg, an auto repair shop will likely have an office/breakroom towards the rear of the building.

Comment: @HotLicks -- I thought about this; you'd typically use "in [the] back" for in the back room, the "out" in this construction implies outside.  If Alice is "out back" of the auto shop, I'd infer that she's outside in the alley or whatever that lies outdoors behind the shop.

Comment: You'd think, but "out back" is sometimes used as I suggest.